# How to export numpy array without brackets

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python and I want to export a NumPy array without brackets.

For example,

[image]

to

[image]

Note that there are an odd number of elements in the array.

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Didn't understand what did you mean by exporting? or you just need to print them? If you want to print them without brackets you can do the following:

```
    import numpy as np

    a = np.asarray([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]])
               
    for item in a:
       a_str = np.array2string(item, precision=2, separator=' ')
       print(' ' + a_str[1:-1])

    print(a)
```

Comment: Sorry. I mean I want to save the array to a .dat file. Anyway, thank you so much for your help. Now I save it by `np.savetxt('test.dat', arr, fmt='%i\t%i')`

Answer (score 0):

To save a NumPy array to a file, you can use numpy's [`savetxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

```
np.savetxt('test.out', fmt='%d', arr)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reminder. I solved it by `np.savetxt('test.dat', arr, fmt='%i\t%i')`